# jQuery menu with links each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am confused when working with a left side bootstrap menu. I want the jQuery script to add/remove the class "active" at each click and if one menuitem already is active it should remove the "active" class on the other item and add it to the one just clicked, just like a normal menu.

Now I have been able to do so all the items are separated and if clicked, it add/remove that "active" class. I have tried to use the .each() method but I didnt get it to work.
I'm thankful for all help I can get.

```
                 $(document).ready(function(){
                        $(".menuitem1").click(function () {
                            var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
                            if ( $( "#menuitem1" ).hasClass( "active" ) ) {

                                $( ".menuitem1" ).removeClass( "active" );
                            }
                                  else {
                                    $( ".menuitem1" ).addClass( "active" );
                                }
                            }
                        );
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nRs72/

As you an see, all the elements are seperated and it has no idea if another one is active. With this current code I need to do this to all the elements in the menu.  Anyone who have an idea how I can do this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you don't need to loop through each of them. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/nRs72/1/)**. I added class `.left-menu` to your `ul`

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked left-menu">
</ul>
```

---

```
$('ul.left-menu li').on('click', function () {
    var isActive = $(this).hasClass('active');
    $('ul.left-menu li').removeClass('active');
    if (!isActive) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a lot of extra work by attaching a click handler to each menu item. jQuery will return a list of all elements matching a selector, so this will allow you to attach your event to all matched elements. (You will need all of your menu items to have a common selector, like a 'menuitem' class.)  jQuery's .siblings method will allow you to grab the .menuitem with the 'active' class and then remove that class.

```
$(".menuitem").click(function () {
    var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change the classes to be menuitem and then:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                        $(".menuitem").click(function () {

                            if ( $( this ).hasClass( "active" ) ) {
                                //do nothing
                            }
                            else {
                                 $( ".menuitem" ).each(function() {$(this.removeClass("active");});
                                 $(this).addClass( "active" );
                            }
                           }
                        );
```